# changing the icon badge number when local notification fires

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I need to increase the icon badge number everytime a local notification gets fired to inform the user that there is one more question he needs to answer. When the user answers a question of any sent notification the icon badge number is beeing reduced by 1. I only have one-time notifications, no recurring.

Since the app is not running when the notification fires I do not have any idea how to increase the icon badge number at that time. While there is no problem to decrease the number when the user answers a question - since this is done within the app.

Is there any possibility  - maybe similar to `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` for push notifications?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UILocalNotification` class has a property `applicationIconBadgeNumber` of type `NSInteger`, which you can set, when scheduling the local notification.

Comment: I know - but this is too early to set the badge number to 1 for instance, since the notification has not been sent. I need to set it to 1 once the notification fires to indicate that there is an outstanding question. and increase it by one for any new question. I am not sure if this is possible on iPhone at all. Thanks!

Comment: But this will set the badge number when the notification fires, not when you schedule it.

Comment: Oh, ok, I did not think of that. Somehow this should work. Thanks!

Comment: @graver, your statement " this will set the badge number when the notification fires" is not accurate. It does not happen when the notification fires, the badge number is set when notification is scheduled.

Comment: @user387184 Have you found a solution ?